# jQuery mobile panel not fully rendering on device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have been creating this app for mobiles using Phonegap and jquery mobile, all has been going well until I try and run it on my actual device (HTC Flyer Android 3.2.1). There appears to be some kind of rendering issue.

Just to note this only appears to happen on device, not when using an emulator, or in a browser on my computer. When I slide right to open the settings panel it does not fully render. Pictures will show this better:

This is what is supposed to happen when the panel opens:

[image: Rendering fine]

But this is what actually happens:

[image: Not rendering fine]

When I touch the button or heading on the panel it seems to refresh itself and render's fine, which is odd, as both of the above are screen captures form device.

Upon discovering this I added this code:

```
$("#SettingsPanel").trigger("create");
```

To see if recreating it would help. I know this isn't a great thing to do preformance wise but I had no other idea's
I wanted to test on another more powerful device to see if it was a performance thing, but I don't have any other devices to test on.

So now I'm stuck and I'd like some help please.

Comment: Have you tried on a different device? `.trigger('create')` wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Is this a custom slide panel, or the jquery mobile slide panel?

Comment: This is a jquery Mobile slide panel